# Display SKU in magento product import data-flow profiles

Tags: magento, import, dataflow, profiles

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAluR.png

Pls see the screenshot above

Is there any way we can display the product SKU in question in front of the error? Or at least the line number of the imported CSV file?

This should be fairly straightforward process if you know where to edit. Which I dont :D please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dataflow error messages are generated by:

`app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Convert/Profile/Run.php`

Copy this file to:

`app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Convert/Profile/Run.php`

and look for the following:

```
'template' => '<li style="#{style}" id="#{id}">'
    . '<img id="#{id}_img" src="#{image}" class="v-middle" style="margin-right:5px"/>'
    . '<span id="#{id}_status" class="text">#{text}</span>'
    . '</li>',
'text'     => $this->__('Processed <strong>%s%% %s/%d</strong> records', '#{percent}', '#{updated}', $this->getBatchItemsCount()),
'successText'  => $this->__('Imported <strong>%s</strong> records', '#{updated}')
```

Change:

```
. '<span id="#{id}_status" class="text">#{text}</span>'
```

To:

```
. '<span id="#{id}_status" class="text">Row #{id} - #{text}</span>'
```